# Couchbase index suggestions

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have a bucket containing documents like this:
{
"x" : "x",
"y" : "y",
"z" : "z",
//...
}

And I have a GSI index on 2 properties (x,y).

I'd like to know which of these scenarios is supposed to be more performant if I want to query the document by x and y:

```
1- SELECT * from bucket where x = "x" and y = "y"

2- 
    * SELECT meta().id from bucket where x = "x" and y = "y"
    * SELECT * from bucket USE KEYS [The keys returned by previous query]
```

Answer (score 3):

As @deniswsrosa suggested Option 1 performs better.
As the index has all the information about query predicate and IndexScan able to produce exact number of documents (no false positives). Checkout https://blog.couchbase.com/create-right-index-get-right-performance/

Depends on the how many documents query qualifies there might be better options.
As query required "data Fetch", the data needs to go through 2 hops ( Data Node to Query Service, Query Service to Client). If the resultant documents or less and size is small option 1 works fine.

If resultant document count are high and size also high you can explore the following option.

1. Using covering query produce the document keys

   SELECT meta().id from bucket where x = "x" and y = "y"
2. Then use Couchbase SDKs Asynchronous API and directly get the documents from Data Node.

Comment: I need to return a full -relatively- big objects so Covered index are not an option in my case. 
So if I understand well from both answers, it'd be better in my case to choose the 1 query to avoid the 2 synchrone calls (fetch ids then fetch documents)?

Comment: In that case create index that covers predicates (cover index) and then use SDK fetch the documents.

Answer (score 2):

The first one should significantly faster, essentially because you are running one query instead of 2. However, as you are using "select *" in both queries, you will trigger "data fetch" which is ok in most cases, but if you need maximum performance you should try to use cover indexes instead https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/covering-indexes.html